# Code not validating, possible incorrect markup?

Tags: php, html, validation, w3c-validation

I'm having trouble Validating this code with W3C with doctype `<!doctype html>` which as far as i'm aware is the HTML5 doc type.

```
     <?php 
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture01.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture01.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture One'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture02.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture02.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Two'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture03.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture03.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Three'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture04.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture04.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Four'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture05.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture05.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Five'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture06.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture06.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Six'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture07.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture07.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Seven'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture08.jpg?".filemtime ('uploads/picture08.jpg')."' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Eight'/>";

   ?>
```

The errors I am getting for each line are;

[image]

Generated Code,

```
<img src='uploads/picture01.jpg?1405031988' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture One'/>
<img src='uploads/picture02.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Two'/>
<img src='uploads/picture03.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Three'/>
<img src='uploads/picture04.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Four'/>
<img src='uploads/picture05.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Five'/>
<img src='uploads/picture06.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Six'/>
<img src='uploads/picture07.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Seven'/>
<img src='uploads/picture08.jpg?1397567043' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Eight'/>
```

NB. i've appended filetime to each image to stop browser caching of the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing `'` after the image name:

```
<?php 
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture01.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture01.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture One'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture02.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture02.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Two'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture03.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture03.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Three'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture04.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture04.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Four'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture05.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture05.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Five'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture06.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture06.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Six'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture07.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture07.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Seven'/>";
   echo "<img src='uploads/picture08.jpg?" .filemtime ('uploads/picture08.jpg') . "' class='img' alt='Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Eight'/>";

   ?>
```

EDIT: Swapping around the double and single quotes

```
<?php 
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture01.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture01.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture One" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture02.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture02.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Two" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture03.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture03.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Three" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture04.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture04.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Four" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture05.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture05.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Five" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture06.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture06.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Six" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture07.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture07.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Seven" />';
   echo '<img src="uploads/picture08.jpg?' .filemtime ('uploads/picture08.jpg') . '" class="img" alt="Bass Clef Photography Demo Picture Eight" />';

   ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that does allow the markup to be displayed properly now when viewing the page after server side rendering, however the errors still persist.

Comment: I've amended the question with new markup as you suggested, and with new error messages.

Comment: Could you also post the HTML that is generated?

Comment: You're sure those errors are form that code? I don't see any of the errors it's talking about in there.

Comment: Yes they definitely are, the line numbers match up and when i double click on the error it takes me to the exact place in the line. For example if i double click on "a slash was not immediately followed by >" it takes me to the "/" in this snippet ('uploads/picture02.jpg')

Comment: Give my edit a try. I swapped the double and single quotes. It may not like the singles.

Comment: That did it, thank you very much @Samsquanch. I thought you could use them both interchangeably.

Comment: I think by HTML5 spec you can use them interchangeably. Maybe the validator knows something we don't?

Answer (score 1):

The [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/) checks if a document uses valid **HTML**.

You got the errors because you tried to validate a document that contains **PHP**: the validator tries to interpret it as HTML.

Solution: Validate the generated document (after PHP ran). You’ll see that your snippet is valid HTML5.